# How to write a signingout code in android

Tags: android, sqlite, logout

I am creating an application that consists of registration page and Login page using SQlite database and i want to logout from that activity after clicking Logout button and is there any code for logout. I google it and many of them showed using shared preferences, But here i used sqlitedatabse not the shared preferences.Is the logic is same for the logout using shared preferences and sqlitedatabase in android can any one help me please how to write logout code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sqlite database to store the registration and login details then you can have a flag column in the table to check if the user is logged in or not. Or you can delete the record of the logged in user when he logs out. If you use shared preference it would be easy as you just need to delete the contents in the shared preferences file when he logs out and insert the data into the file when he logs in.